# Append inverse_scale NN output and model.predict_classes output into a csv

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have trained a Neural Network and I want to append the prediction values to inverse_scaled test data so I can check the predictions vs the original feature values. However, when I run the code, the following line:

```
Xtest["prediciton"] = pred
```

throws the following error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I believe that is because after the following line, `Xtest` becomes a np.array:

```
Xtest = scaler.inverse_transform(Xtest)
```

Here's the full code:

```
import keras
import numpy
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from IPython.core.display import display
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

data_num = pd.read_csv('mult_test.csv')
print(data_num.head(n=10))

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
features = data_num.drop(['Label1'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
features = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(features))
scale_num_data = pd.concat([data_num['Label1'], features], axis=1)


dtrain, dtest = train_test_split(scale_num_data, test_size=0.25, random_state=570)
X = dtrain.drop(['Label1'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
y = dtrain['Label1']
Xtest = dtest.drop(['Label1'], axis=1, errors='ignore')
Xtest.to_csv('X_test_1.csv')
ytest = dtest['Label1']


model = Sequential([
    Dense(10, input_shape=(4, ), activation='relu'),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)


scores = model.evaluate(Xtest, ytest, batch_size=5)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))


pred = model.predict_classes(Xtest)
Xtest = scaler.inverse_transform(Xtest)
Xtest["prediciton"] = pred
Xtest.to_csv("Xtest_predict.csv")
```

Thank you for your help, guys!

Answer (score 0):

scikit's `transformers` don't preserve panda dataframes. So when you pass one through a `transform` or `inverse_transform`, `np.ndarray` comes out.

You tried to access the `Xtest`'s item `'prediction'`, but that's not a valid position item for an `np.ndarray`.

To fix this, just create a new `DataFrame` or don't dump `scaler.inverse_transform` directly onto `Xtest`:

```py
results = pd.DataFrame({
  "data": scaler.inverse_transform(Xtest),
  "predictions": model.predict_classes(Xtest)
})
results.to_csv("Xtest_predict.csv")
```